# Rule builder shipping postal code exclusion leads to no shipping when not logged in yet

Tags: shopware, shopware6

whe created shipping rules, because we have to have to exclude shipping to isles for some products and/or some shipping methods. therefore we used the built-in *shipping address: postal code* option.

[image]

Problem is, when someone is not logged in yet, they dont get any shipping methods that use a postal code rule. so they get the message

> "%oldShippingMethodName%" shipping is not available for your current cart, the shipping was changed to "%newShippingMethodName%".

After login or adding the address without creating an account, the other shipping is available again, but not preset as default anymore, even if higher prioritised.

So we have a preferable shipping method, but thats not working as primary one, because of this. anything we can do here to make things right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I see it you want to keep the shipping method available as long as the customer is not logged in, respectively has no billing address yet. You could logically chain the billing-zip-code-condition with the customer-is-logged-in-condition so that either one has to be true to make the shipping method available.

[image]